# print() IndentationError: python language

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a very beginner to python, I dont know what is this error, help

I'm trying this

my example

```
i = 10
if i % 2 == 0:
print("Number is even")
else:
print("Number is odd")
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITtWk.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python expects indentations underneath `if` statements and `else` statements. This should work.

```
i = 10
if i % 2 == 0:
    print("Number is even")
else:
    print("Number is odd")
```

For further clarification, essentially any Python statement that ends in a `:` is generally gonna be followed by an indented code block. The indented code block includes all the statements that you want Python to execute.

In this case, `if` and `else` both have the same level of indentation and each of them has a statement that follows that needs to be indented.

Comment: It's sufficient to say statements; one type of statement is the expression statement, which consists of a single expression.